# is it possible to do a cpanel to cpanel folder copy on the same server without downloading on home pc?

Tags: cpanel, copy

Is it possible to copy a folder from a cpanel account to another cpanel account without first downloading to home pc ?

I have some issues with the upload speed of my internet connection so i prefer not to  download it to home pc first.

Both cpanel accounts are on the same hosting server and I have access to whm under which both cpanel accounts have been created.

Comment: Does your Host Have a WebFTP Interface?  Yoy may be able to from there

Comment: Do you have shell access to do a cp (copy) command? That may be your best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Connect to your server with SSH and use the `cp` command to copy the files

Some basic examples of `cp` here http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucp.htm

Other people have asked a similar question on cpanel.net and they got the same answer to use SSH

http://forums.cpanel.net/f34/how-copy-file-between-2-account-186101.html

`rsync` is another command you should look into

Comment: mv is move which is not copy. mv will remove the original files from the original location. The OP uses the term copy. mv can be dangerous. OP, use cp to copy. As well, the OP would have to check file ownership which may or may not not change. Can you edit your answer to reflect these? I would love to up-vote your answer.

Comment: @closetnoc edited

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. mv scares me... is it just me or everyone??

Comment: Not as much as working from #

Comment: If trying to copy cross account, you may need to use the `-p` (preserve) or `-a` (archive mode) flag on copy, then chown the copied file(s), else stuff may not run.

Answer (score 0):

If you're copying **within the same cPanel account** then you can use the **File Manager** for this purpose. Simply right-click the file or folder and choose "Copy".

[image: cPanel file manager copy]

If the file needs to be copied to *another* cPanel account, then you may need root-level SSH access to the server, or if you don't have root access, you might be able to connect to an SSH shell and then use SCP/FTP to transfer the files between the two accounts.